# automatic hidden redirect from one html page to another

Tags: redirect

I'm pretty new to web programming. The whole project links two shops together.

One of our customer's who owns the first shob has provided some sort of an Event API which sends a request to one of our simple html/js files when an event occurs (different ones are specified - e.g. a new customer was created which needs to be synchronised between the shop databases). Included in his GET request is an URL as parameter.

We have to parse this given URL, sending a request to this URL and "reading" what the actual content of the event is (name of the new customer etc.), writing it into our database and giving a reponse to the initial request from the other shop (sucess or failure).

How can I do this in a simple way in an html/js file without setting up web services etc.? Don't bother about the database actions, its taken care of  .. its about the automatic redirecting ..

Many Thx ..

J

Comment: What do you mean "without setting up web services etc"? If he is making a GET request, then somewhere there's a server receiving this request. Have you thought of using PHP? Is that an option? A couple of lines of PHP with a cURL request would be all it takes.

Comment: I'm confused about the need for a redirect. What are you redirecting to? It sounds like you just want a success/failure response. An HTTP response code should work for that. Something in the 200s for success and something in the... 500s? for failure? Unless it's authentication or a missing resource or something along those lines, in which case the 400s are more appropriate. See [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), but be warned that there is some subtle nomenclature. Also, not sure how you could parse a URL or interact with a database without a web framework.

Comment: How are you parsing the URL and interacting with the database? ASP.NET web app? PHP? Ruby or Python framework? If you're using a framework, it almost certainly has something for controlling the HTTP status code in the response and for redirecting. Telling us what you're using might give you a more specific answer.

Comment: Hi,thx for your reply .. I just wanted to use javascript (embedded in an html page), parse it through a js-function when the html page is called and re-direct immediately .. possible?